# Break out of a function quietly and no-debug using if statement (or anything else)

Tags: r, function, if-statement

#### Is it possible to break out of a function quietly and no-debug using `if` statement (or anything else)?

###### Purpose: I would like to escape from a function (like the break statement in `for` loop) if specific conditions were met. The function is expected to be utilized in the similar way as `mean()` (for example) and sometimes within *dplyr* manipulation and `for` loop. Besides, I wish to avoid complex nested `if-else` statement.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 5, 1, 2)

break5 <- function(x){
    # If this exception occur, then
    # end up (escape ?) the whole function
    if (x == 5){
        # next      # <-- This will raise error message
        break     # <-- This will raise error message
        # stop()  # <-- This will raise debugging event
    } 
    
    # Otherwise, proceed the subsequent process
    if (x == 1) print(1)
    if (x == 2) print(2)
}
```

##### Console Output:

```
> break5(1)
[1] 1

> break5(2)
[1] 2

> break5(5)
Error in break5(5) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

### Expect to get silent result as the `break` in `for` loop

```
for (i in v){
    if (i == 5) break # <-- Similar with this procedure that 
                      #     could be included in the function
    break5(i)
}
```

##### Example 1

```
x0 <- 1:100
y0 <- 1:100

example <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL){
  
  if (is.null(x) | is.null(y)){    
    break                            # Case 1
  }
  
  if (!(x %in% x0) | !(y %in% y0)){
    break                            # Case 2
  }
  
  if (x < 2){
    z <- 1                           # Case 3
    return(z)
  }
  
  if ((x >= 80) & (x <= 100)){
    break                            # Case 4
  }
  
  z <- x + y                        # Otherwise
  return(z)
}

example(1)    # Case 1, this should be muted
example(30, 999)    # Case 2, this should be muted
example(1, 1)    # Case 3, this is OK
example(80, 1)    # Case 4, this should be muted
example(11, 1)    # Otherwise, this is OK
```

##### Example 2:

```
for (i in 75:90){
  print(paste0(i, '+', i, '=', example(i, i)))  # The rest should be muted
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can break out of a `for` loop with a function like that without throwing an error. However, you should not need that. It looks like poor design.

Comment: What does "I would like to end up a function if specific conditions was met." mean exactly? Your example is totally different, i.e., it tries to break out of a `for` loop. To my knowledge, you can't do what you want to do with a `for` loop because `for` and `break` are special `.Primitive` functions.

Comment: I'm asking about the exact intended side effect of your function. You can't break out of a `for` loop as a side effect (AFAIK). But you might be able to do other stuff (like returning from the calling function).

Comment: I am afraid that my crappy description had misled your comprehension on the question. Unfortunately, I'm currently not capable to make this clearer. Anyway, thanks for your earnest comment.

Comment: You mention this could be used within `dplyr`. Say I call your function in `dplyr`, `some_data %>% mutate(new_column = example(some_input))`. The way `dplyr` works, `mutate` is creating a new column and filling it with the result of the call to `example`. There will be an error if `breaks` doesn't return something that can fill the column--I don't think there's any way to avoid that from inside the `example` function.

Comment: Instead, I think you might want to look at some of the nice wrappers in `purrr` - `quietly`, `safely`, `possibly`... that might help you accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible to do so by returning a `suppressWarnings()` expr.

```
x0 <- 1:100
y0 <- 1:100

example <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL){
    
    if (is.null(x) | is.null(y)){
        return(suppressWarnings(warning()))     # Case 1
    }
    warning
    if (!(x %in% x0) | !(y %in% y0)){
        return(suppressWarnings(warning()))     # Case 2
    }
    
    if (x < 2){
        z <- 1                                  # Case 3
        return(z)
    }
    
    if ((x >= 80) & (x <= 100)){
        return(suppressWarnings(warning()))     # Case 4
    }
    
    z <- x + y                                  # Otherwise
    return(z)
}
```

#### Example 1

```
example(1)          # Case 1, Error/Warning message was muted
example(30, 999)    # Case 2, Error/Warning message was muted
example(1, 1)       # Case 3, this is OK
example(80, 1)      # Case 4, Error/Warning message was muted
example(11, 1)      # Otherwise, this is OK
```

##### Console output:

```
> example(1)
> example(30, 999) 
> example(1, 1) 
[1] 1
> example(80, 1)
> example(11, 1)
[1] 12
```

#### Example 2

```
for (i in 75:90){
    print(paste0(i, '+', i, '=', example(i, i)))  # The rest was muted
}
```

##### Console output:

```
> for (i in 75:90){
+     print(paste0(i, '+', i, '=', example(i, i)))
+ }
[1] "75+75=150"
[1] "76+76=152"
[1] "77+77=154"
[1] "78+78=156"
[1] "79+79=158"
[1] "80+80="
[1] "81+81="
[1] "82+82="
[1] "83+83="
[1] "84+84="
[1] "85+85="
[1] "86+86="
[1] "87+87="
[1] "88+88="
[1] "89+89="
[1] "90+90="
```